# How to get remote access after VPN connection?

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, openvpn, remote-access, teamviewer

I am trying to access a remote machine through a VPN.

I am connecting to VPN using the following command:

```
sudo openvpn --config file.ovpn
```

The connection is successfully established:

> Tue Sep 26 01:50:06 2017 Initialization Sequence Completed

After this, I am searching how to do a remote access, but without success. Can anyone help me with this? How to use something like teamviewer? I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: What's the operating system on the host for the remote session? Do you want to access a terminal, run GUI applications or access the entire desktop?

Comment: Access the entire desktop, @David . I already got success, using remmina. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After connect to VPN using `openvpn`, I used `remmina`, a tool to remote desktop access already installed on Ubuntu.

I just opened it, put the right IP enabled for remote access (server IP) through the VPN and clicked on connect button. Then, in the dialog box opened, I put the right credentials for the remote machine (login and password).

Comment: If both machine are connected with different wi fi but same VPN then which IP should i use ?